# automation of shell script to read all its input from a file instead of a keyboard

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, keyboard

Suppose I have a shell script which take inputs from keyboard. I want to write all the inputs in a file and then use that file for providing inputs to the script instead of using the keyboard. Is it possible? If yes how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 'here string' can do this for you. Usage: `command <<< $WORD`. And of course each entry has to be on a separate line like so:

```
first variable
second variable
third variable
```

And a simple example from the below mentioned site:

```
# Instead of:
if echo "$VAR" | grep -q txt   # if [[ $VAR = *txt* ]]
# etc.

# Try:
if grep -q "txt" <<< "$VAR"
then   #         ^^^
   echo "$VAR contains the substring sequence \"txt\""
fi
# Thank you, Sebastian Kaminski, for the suggestion.
```

Info:

- `$WORD`: This is the file containing the information to be fed to the command, in this case the file containing the values the command needs to run.

See: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html

Comment: Can you clarify what `$source` is, in the context of the OP's question? `command <<< $source` runs `command` with the value of the shell variable `source` as its standard input. The OP wants to read inputs from a file. Are you recommending they make a script that puts them in shell variable instead, or perhaps that they read a file into a shell variable? It [seems to me](https://askubuntu.com/a/1150664/22949) that the OP should just create the file, then redirect input from it. Their problem *could* be solved with here strings, but I'm unsure how (or why) you're recommending to do it that way.

Comment: @eliahkagan, I think I wrote it wrong as my link points to a 'hair string' example and that is what I was suggesting in my example.

Answer (score 1):

When

- you know exactly what information the program or script needs, *and*
- you know *the order* in which the information is needed, *and*
- you do not *also* need to provide input to it from your terminal

...then this is very simple. You can just use [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input), and the simplest form of input redirection suffices.

```
./script < answers
```

Replace `./script` with whatever command actually runs the program or script and `answers` with a path to the file that contains all the inputs.

(You can also write this as `< answers ./script` if you find that to be more convenient. In either case, `<` comes just before `answers`--you can even write `<answers`--and if you have other command-line arguments that must be passed to `./script`, that's fine.)

The way this works is that, by default, [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) is usually a terminal, but you can redirect it to any [file or device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file). The shell operator `<` redirects standard input. For more details, and the full story on redirection, see [*Redirections*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

---

On the other hand, if you don't know quite what information the program or script will prompt for--and so you need to specify answers for questions that may or may not be asked, or may be asked in any order, or may be asked with important variations--then you'll want to write another script that handles providing the necessary inputs. There are tools to automate this; often, [`expect`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/expect.1.html) is a good choice. From what you said, though, it doesn't sound like you need this. (If you do, you should give more details.)

Comment: thank you for the answer it worked well.